# python decorators stacking

Tags: python, functional-programming, decorator

I have been trying to understand better the decorators and closures.

I am trying to decorate the function to achieve:

- remembering previously passed values,
- counting how many times the function was called.

I want to make it using two separate decorators - for science :)

So I managed to create this **working** code (I used some snippet for the counting - I admit)

```
class countcalls(object):
    "Decorator that keeps track of the number of times a function is called."

    __instances = {}

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.__f = f
        self.__numcalls = 0
        countcalls.__instances[f] = self

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__numcalls += 1
        return self.__f(*args, **kwargs)

    def count(self):
        "Return the number of times the function f was called."
        return countcalls.__instances[self.__f].__numcalls

    @staticmethod
    def counts():
        "Return a dict of {function: # of calls} for all registered functions."
        return dict([(f.__name__, countcalls.__instances[f].__numcalls) for f in countcalls.__instances])

def wrapper(x):
    past=[]
    @countcalls
    def inner(y):
        print x 
        print inner.count()
        past.append(y)
        print past

    return inner

def main():
    foo = wrapper("some constant")

    foo(5)
    foo("something")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output:

```
some constant
1
[5]
some constant
2
[5, 'something']
```

Now I want to change the memoize function to a neat pythonic decorator. Here is what I came out with so far:

```
class countcalls(object):
    "Decorator that keeps track of the number of times a function is called."

    __instances = {}

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.__f = f
        self.__numcalls = 0
        countcalls.__instances[f] = self

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__numcalls += 1
        return self.__f(*args, **kwargs)

    def count(self):
        "Return the number of times the function f was called."
        return countcalls.__instances[self.__f].__numcalls

    @staticmethod
    def counts():
        "Return a dict of {function: # of calls} for all registered functions."
        return dict([(f.__name__, countcalls.__instances[f].__numcalls) for f in countcalls.__instances])


class memoize(object):
    past=[]

    def __init__(self, f):
        past = []
        self.__f = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.past.append(*args)

        return self.__f(*args, **kwargs)

    def showPast(self):
        print self.past


@memoize
@countcalls
def dosth(url):
    print dosth._memoize__f.count()  ## <-- this is so UGLY
    dosth.showPast()

def main():
    dosth("one")
    dosth("two")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here is the output:

```
1
['one']
2
['one', 'two']
```

How to get rid of the "ugly" line ( `print dosth._memoize__f.count()` ) ? In other words - how can I directly call the methods of the stacked decorators? (without adding a method to the decorators to call the methods of other decorators - that is not my point)

Comment: Why are you accessing the decorators from within the function *at all*?

Comment: i figured in this case its a good way to count how many times the function was called and modify the behavior of the function depending on it
it doesnt matter anyway - if i want to access the count property outside of the function - i still need to use  dosth._memoize__f.count()

Comment: Not if you put the counter *outside* the memoizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll still have to unwrap the decorators if you want to access specific decorator results, but the 'default' attribute for this is `__wrapped__`. The Python 3 version of the [`@functools.wraps()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) sets this attribute for you (via the [`functools.update_wrapper()` utility function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper), starting with Python 3.4), but you can do the same manually in your own decorators:

```
class memoize(object):
    past=[]

    def __init__(self, f):
        past = []
        self.__wrapped__ = self.__f = f
```

Now you can access the wrapped callable with:

```
dosth.__wrapper__.count()
```

wich is the *standard* Pythonic way of unwrapping decorators.